# Firebase Storage/Firestore unauthorized due to no Auth object on Rules

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

**Update**

I use this plugin to Phone auth https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication. So how can I transfer that Auth details to the AngulraFireAuth?

```
  async signIn(): Promise<void> {
      await this.firebaseAuthentication.signInWithVerificationId(verificationId, securityCode);   
  }
```

auth.service.ts

```
 onAuthStateChanged(): void {
    this.firebaseAuthentication.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe((res) => {

      this.zone.run(async () => {
        if (res) {
           // code
        });
    });
  }
```

**Original**

I have a Firebase Storage bucket permission like so: Same for the `Firestore` too.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write:if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Client-side code: i.e. upload an image

```
 console.log('user', await this.afAuth.currentUser); //null

 const filePath: string = `signatures/${user.uid}`;

 const afUploadTask: AngularFireUploadTask = afStorageReference.putString(imageDataUrl, 'data_url');
```

But it fails:

> vendor.js:44100 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
> FirebaseStorageError:
> {"code_":"storage/unauthorized","message_":"Firebase Storage: User
> does not have permission to access
> 'signatures/gx3TlaSFQoPhQXCnjk3QCrq2j9x1'.","serverResponse_":"{\n
> "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission
> denied. Could not perform this operation"\n
> }\n}","name_":"FirebaseError"}

So how can I configure this kind of rule with Storage? Without any rule above code is working fine.

Comment: Your Storage rules are not checking for any path, so they should accept a write when there's an authenticated user. Since they don't accept the write, the most logical conclusion is that the user isn't authenticated (yet) when this write starts. What I typically do is `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` on the line before the upload starts, to see what the user auth state really is at that point.

Comment: Unrelated: since your question seems to have nothing to do with Firestore, I'd remove those rules from your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I use Phone auth and I can go to the above image page only if Auth is a success there. Any clue then?

Comment: I'm not sure how this related to what I proposed. Did you add the `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` statement? If so, can you update your question to show the updated code and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you're right. I use this plugin to Phone Auth since this is an Ionic app: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication So how can I transfer that user to AngularFireAuth user?

Comment: The code I shared is plain JavaScript SDK, not the AngularFire wrapper. I'd start with the lower level to rules out all the additional layers.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry, I didn't get you? How can I transfer my plugin's user state to Firebase SDK auth?

Comment: @Sampath it looks like you're on an Ionic app and are using a plugin to authenticate the user through the native iOS/android SDKs but you're trying to handle the interaction with Storage or Firestore through the web SDK. I don't know if that works, at the moment you try to use Storage from teh web sdk the request can't find any auth state there

Comment: @javebratt Yes, this is the exact issue here. Do you know how to inject or do custom rule to match with Plugin's Auth state as valid one for Storage rules?

Comment: IMO, the very first thing you should look at is how to get the `currentUser` to be non-null on your client app.  If you can't find out how/why you are authenticated to Firebase, then when you access Firebase services like Storage you'll be out of luck.  Once you have `currentUser` (or *any* approach for having a Firebase authenticated user) on the client side, then you can investigate whether that auth is also being sent to Firebase services.

Comment: @mobiGeek You didn't get my issue here. Please read `javebratt` comment above.

Comment: I do and I have.  Do you have access to a Firebase auth object (a `user`) in your client app?  In your code above, you indicated that it is `null`.  Until your client app has a handle on a valid user context, looking at the server configuration is mainly a waste of time.  Once you have a handle on the user object on the client app (i.e. it is not `null`), then we can talk about how you are communicating with the server to ensure that auth object is being passed effectively.

Comment: @mobiGeek I have it. But it is a native SDK auth object. i.e. not compatible with web SDK where it requires to have on rules definitions. I have this: https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication#signinwithverificationidverificationid-smscode

Comment: So have you used [onAuthStateChanged()](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication#onauthstatechangedcallback) to confirm that you have a valid authentication object ("userInfo")?  If so, then when you access Firebase services, you should be seeing that same userInfo available in those services and their rules.

Comment: @mobiGeek Yes, I can use Phone login with the above Native plugin. i.e. no issue there. But web SDK doesn't have any knowledge about it at all. That is why it shows `null` user. We need to find out a way to inject those details to the web SDK hence it doesn't take it by default.

Comment: Please show us your code where you authenticate the user (i.e. the code where you are calling [signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication#signinwithemailandpasswordemail-password) and how you are accessing the user/auth object thereafter.  For example, are you calling [getCurrentUser()](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication#getcurrentuser) ?

Comment: Also, it seems like you are mixing paradigms.  Why use a native Cordova plugin for authentication rather than using [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) and staying in the Javascript space the whole time?  (Note: I've not touched Cordova since the PhoneGap days...).

Note: If you are still after using Cordova, there are a few [Cordova/Firebase-Storage projects on GitHub](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=cordova+firebase-storage&type=Repositories) that might be worth reviewing?

Comment: @mobiGeek Updated. I do not use `getCurrentUser()` since I get the data from `onAuthStateChanged()`. This is not only for Storage the same for the Firestore. i.e. no Auth user for web SDK. I need a Native SDK since it doesn't use reCapture. But web has it and I need to avoid that on mobile devices.

Comment: I use the web SDK for authentication (signInWithEmailAndPassword()) and I don't get reCapture'ed at all.  Are you thinking about the FirebaseUI?  I don't use that, instead go straight to the [auth-password API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

Comment: @mobiGeek reCapture is mandatory only on Phone auth with the web SDK. Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth